# sugarcrm 6.4.4 mail client-Lead history- Details are missing

Tags: php, email, crm, sugarcrm

1. I'm using sugarcrm 6.4.4 and configured my mail id using IMAP.
2. Also i'm using same id for web-based mail (gmail).
3. When i try to see the histories for leads, it is showing only the sent histories through sugarcrm, i would like to view the web-base sent histories also in the lead section.

Note: When i try to forward mails from sugarcrm to others, the attachments are missing. I'm using shared server hosted in hostgator, the error logs shows

Mon Feb 4 01:33:25 2013 [30702][1][ERROR] convert: Conversion of 2013-02-04 from Y-m-d H:i:s to h:ia failed
Mon Feb 4 01:33:43 2013 [31332][-none-][FATAL] Configuration variable date.timezone is not set, guessed timezone America/Chicago. Please set date.timezone="America/Chicago" in php.ini!
Mon Feb 4 01:33:48 2013 [31634][-none-][FATAL] Configuration variable date.timezone is not set, guessed timezone America/Chicago. Please set date.timezone="America/Chicago" in php.ini!
Mon Feb 4 01:34:16 2013 [32557][-none-][FATAL] Configuration variable date.timezone is not set, guessed timezone America/Chicago. Please set date.timezone="America/Chicago" in php.ini!

Any help would be very much appreciated.

With Kind Regards,

B.C.Rajkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an email archiving solution, such as the one that comes with Sugar Pro and above...

http://www.sugarcrm.com/feature/email-integration#email